# UITableview merging with the home indicator on iPhone X

Tags: objective-c, ios11, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I have a `UITableView` created programmatically. This `UITableView` merges with the home indicator on an iPhone X device.

How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programatically, set bottom anchor of tableview with bottom anchor of SafeAreaLayout.

Here is sample/test code, how to programatically set safe area layout with respect to interface elements.

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
  let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
  NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
   table.topAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(guide.topAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
   guide.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(table.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 1.0)
   ])

} else {
   let standardSpacing: CGFloat = 8.0
   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
   table.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
   bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: table.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
   ])
}
```

Here are useful references (answers):

- [Use Safe Area Layout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317061/use-safe-area-layout-programmatically/46318300#46318300)
- [Safe Area of Xcode 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492404/safe-area-of-xcode-9/45334411#45334411)

Comment: Can i have an objective c version of it

Comment: Sure, give me some time, will provide you obj-c code. Share me variable name for tableview.

Comment: `self.tableView`

Comment: Did you extend (use) UITableController to display this list or UIViewController?

Comment: UIViewController

Comment: its not working when i am using UITableViewController

Comment: Any Solution for TableViewController ?

Comment: @NimishaRanipa Raise your new question with code you've tried - I'll surely help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [safeAreaLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide) in **iOS11**
& setting the constraints with `safeArea` hence your content will not clip.

For setting constraints in `UITableView`-

**ObjC**

```
    self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    UILayoutGuide * guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
    [self.tableView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.tableView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.tableView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.tableView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
```

**Swift 4**

```
      tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor).isActive = true

        } else {
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if your controller is derived from UI**Table**ViewController (not UIViewController), the cells does not look good bottom of the screen.

[image: cells and home indicator look together]

I assume you are using a navigationController, in this case my solution is:

```
//dummy view
var bottomX: UIView?


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if Device.isIPhoneX {
        bottomX = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.tableView.bounds.size.height - 34, width: self.tableView.bounds.size.width, height: 34))
        bottomX!.backgroundColor = self.tableView.backgroundColor
        self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(bottomX!)
    }
}
```

and don't forget remove dummy view

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    bottomX?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

and the result is :

[image: cells behind dummy view]

this solution is not very nice, but it does work for now

Answer (score 0):

This is my "hack" to force top and bottom safe area in `UITableViewController`. First you have to embed it in `UINavigationController` (hide the navigation bar if not needed), then:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureFakeSafeArea()
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
    super.viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()

    topSafeAreaHeight?.constant = view.safeAreaInsets.top
    bottomSafeAreaHeight?.constant = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
}

private var topSafeAreaHeight: NSLayoutConstraint?
private var bottomSafeAreaHeight: NSLayoutConstraint?

private func configureFakeSafeArea() {
    guard let view = navigationController?.view else {
        return
    }

    let topSafeArea = UIView()
    topSafeArea.backgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor
    var topConstant: CGFloat = 0
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        topConstant = view.safeAreaInsets.top
    }
    topSafeAreaHeight = topSafeArea.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: topConstant)
    view.addSubview(topSafeArea, constraints: [
        topSafeArea.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        topSafeArea.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        topSafeArea.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        topSafeAreaHeight!
    ])

    let bottomSafeArea = UIView()
    bottomSafeArea.backgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor
    var bottomConstant: CGFloat = 0
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        bottomConstant = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    }
    bottomSafeAreaHeight = bottomSafeArea.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: bottomConstant)
    view.addSubview(bottomSafeArea, constraints: [
        bottomSafeArea.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        bottomSafeArea.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        bottomSafeArea.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        bottomSafeAreaHeight!
    ])
}
```

It's just sad that we have to write all this code, so if anyone knows about more simple way to achieve this, please show us.

P.S. I've used this small `UIView` extension here:

```
extension UIView {
    func addSubview(_ child: UIView, constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]) {
        addSubview(child)
        child.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }
}
```