# iPhone X custom tab bar issue

Tags: ios, iphone-x

We have custom tab bar in our app. The height of the custom tab bar is fixed. It was working fine for all devices except iPhone X. The problem is the height of custom tab bar is 45 but in iPhone X it will collide with the home indicator. So we had changed the bottom of the custom tab bar to the safe area. But the problem will be I will see the background view below my custom Tab bar. My question how can we give constraints to Custom tab bar that will be same height all devices except iPhone X and also hides the bottom space in iPhone X?[image: custom tab bar with height 45][image: if I use 45 as the height for Custom tab bar in iPhone X] but I want to increase the height of tab bar in iPhone X but I shouldn't affect other devices. Btw I don't want to write a code to separate iPhone X and other devices. All I want to do it in storyboard itself. [image: Expected iPhone X fix]

Comment: It would help others helping you if you would explain what you have tried to fix your problem, and how it failed meeting your requirements.

Comment: @GwendalRoué Edited my question

Comment: Did you implement safe area layout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317061/use-safe-area-layout-programmatically/46318300#46318300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making a view effect view at the bottom, which is larger than 44pt? I have tried it in my application and it works well.

- refer: https://novemberfive.co/blog/apple-september-event-iphonex-apps/

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

1. set your view to be within safe area
2. set fixed height to your custom tab bar
3. put a view and set margin between safe area bottom and superview bottom

refer to the picture below

Constraints[image]

How it looks like on iPhone X[image]

How it looks like on other iPhone[image]

Comment: @venky You did not mention this in your question. To show and hide the custom tab bar, set a height for custom tab bar as a constraint, then link that to IBOutlet. You will need to programmatically change it during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you with programmatically

```
self.tabBar.layer.masksToBounds = true 
self.tabBar.isTranslucent = true 
self.tabBar.barStyle = .blackOpaque 
self.tabBar.layer.cornerRadius = 20 
self.tabBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
```