# How to draw the layout below the notch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My app stretches through the whole screen of the device. How can I set it to stretch only to the notch area? Ideally, in all screen orientations.

I'm using Objective-C, and Storyboard for the layout.

Thanks for any help. Cannot find the proper documentation, if someone can point me to the correct direction, that would be great.

Comment: Have you heard of autolayout? And the safe area?

Comment: Thanks @matt trying to figure it out. It is set in the Storyboard, but it looks differently on the Simulator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area that you refer to below the notch is called 'safe area'. You can change the top of the view to confine it into the safe area.
Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47076040/19425375

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm using Storyboard for the layout, what you pointed out was a way to set things programatically. Still haven't got it to work properly.

Comment: Enable "Use safe area" on all view elements, and don't forget to "Add missing constraints". Once that is done, enjoy your life while adjusting the visual elements on your storyboard.