# How to add a safe area programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, xcode9, safearealayoutguide

When you open the view, it will look like the image below,

[i Phone x open view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ8uy.png)

[i Phone 8 open view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1T74.png)

For iphone x, I would like to add a safe area programmatically in the current view.

The source to try is as follows.

```
UIView *view = self.view;

if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    UILayoutGuide * guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
    [view.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [view.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
}
```

I suppose to apply this source, but I do not know what to do.

please answer about my question.!

Comment: This source seems to be applicable too.                                
            
            UIWindow *window = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow;
            CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
            CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is sample code for Safe Area Layout. Try this in Objective-C and see:

```
UIView * myView = // initialize view using IBOutlet or programtically

myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor red];
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

UILayoutGuide * guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
[self.myView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
[self.myView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
[self.myView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.topAnchor].active = YES;
[self.myView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:guide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;

// Refresh myView and/or main view
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
//[self.myView layoutIfNeeded];
```

Ref from: [Use Safe Area Layout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317061/use-safe-area-layout-programmatically/46318300#46318300)

Result:

[image]

Comment: myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
If you use this source, the screen will be completely garbled.

Comment: @Nam - I've tried this code practically and here is its result (a red view). It working fine for me.

Comment: @Krunal Instead of reposting your answer over and over, you should vote to close the question as a duplicate.