# Sprite Kit iOS 11 | Place nodes only in safe area

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios11, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I want to program a simple Sprite Kit game in which I have to place some nodes randomly somewhere in the scene.

To ensure that these nodes are not placed outside the safe area I programmed this function:

```
func updatesafearea() {
    let frame = self.size
    let sets = view!.safeAreaInsets
    let rect = CGRect(x: -(frame.width/2)-sets.left,
                      y: -(frame.height/2)-sets.top,
                      width: frame.width-sets.right-sets.left,
                      height: frame.height-sets.top-sets.bottom)
    //Visualize the area
    let node = SKShapeNode(rect: rect)
    node.fillColor = .red
    addChild(node)
}
```

This should be a rect in which all nodes should be presented safely, but unfortunately this doesn't work on iPhone X (Simulator):

iPhone 8 and iPhone X simulator screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Your question isn’t clear enough, please edit it so I can answer your question properly

Comment: This might help answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317061/use-safe-area-layout-programmatically/46318300