# UITabBar with safe area inside programmatically created UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitabbar, safearealayoutguide

*Before you mark it as duplicate please note, that I did read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317061/use-safe-area-layout-programmatically) and this seems to not apply to `UITabBar`*

Both `UIViewController` and `UITabBar` are created programmatically. Constraints are set like:

```
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.tabBar)
}
```

And `self.tabBar`:

```
lazy var tabBar: UITabBar = {
    let tab = UITabBar()
    self.view.addSubview(tab)
    tab.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tab.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    tab.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    tab.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true //This line will change in second part of this post.
    return tab
}()
```

And this show `UITabBar` like this:

[image]

And it's too small cause it's not taking safe areas into consideration. So I did change line:

```
tab.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

to:

```
tab.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

And it's then shown like this:

[image]

So it's also not shown as expected. The goal here is sth like this:

[image]

How to make constraints to show `UITabBar` like this?

Comment: How come you are adding the tab bar yourself? better to use a UITabBarController

Comment: I don't need `UITabBarController`. What's wrong with adding `UITabBar`?

Comment: UITabBarController does alot of the work for you

Comment: I'm familiar with `UITabBarController` and `UITabBar`, I simply don't need most `UITabBarController` functionalities. There is nothing wrong with `UITabBar`. As Apple Docs: ```Typically, you use tab bars in conjunction with a UITabBarController object, but you can also use them as standalone controls in your app.```

Comment: I know that you *can* use it separately, i just asked a question, for clarification

Comment: Do you need it programatically only? I did set it using Interface builder

Comment: Surely you can just set a height constraint of say 100, to the tab bar and that should fix it? You'd have to double check that the device is iPhone X however.

Comment: Yep, I cannot use storyboard for this case unfortunately :/

Answer (score 9):

Here I did it:

```
let tabBar = UITabBar()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addTabbar()
}
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    addHeightConstraintToTabbar()
}

func addTabbar() -> Void {
    self.view.addSubview(tabBar)
    tabBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tabBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    tabBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    tabBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    let item1 = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItem.bookmarks, tag: 1)
    let item2 = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItem.contacts, tag: 2)

    tabBar.items = [item1, item2]
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: tabBar)
}

func addHeightConstraintToTabbar() -> Void {
    let heightConstant:CGFloat = self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom + 49.0
    tabBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightConstant).isActive = true
}
```

Result:

[image]

May not know, is it correct to do in this way. You need to make it better.

Comment: @PranavKasetti You can see result for both device (iPhone-X and other than iPhoneX (iPhone SE)) in answer. Please explain your concern in more detail. You are welcomed to improve quality of this answer by adding you input here.

Comment: how to customer viewControllers to tab items array

Comment: do you understand that `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is called multiple times and you will get a lot of copies of your constraint?

Answer (score 3):

When you add `UItabbar` to UIViewController  and use `safeAreaLayoutGuide` or `layoutMarginsGuide` it will be added to save area of that view controller which have `SafeAreaInsets` with space at bottom you can change, but if you add to View of `UIViewController` it will be stick to edge without any space , with default hight `49`

to increase that hight add  `heightAnchor` constraint

```
  lazy var tabBar: UITabBar = {
        let tab = UITabBar()
        self.view.addSubview(tab)
        tab.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tab.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        tab.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tab.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        tab.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true //This line will change in second part of this post.
        return tab
    }()
```

to use safe area guide you can add negative value to Bottom of `additionalSafeAreaInsets` of ViewController

```
self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -39, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The bottom anchor needs to be connected to view's `safeAreaLayoutGuide`.

```
tabbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    tabbar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    tabbar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
    tabbar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
])
```

Comment: doesn't work with controller: crash "Cannot choose layout method for UITabBar managed by a controller"

Comment: @djdance The original answer is for a custom `UIViewController` with a `UITabBar` added as a subview. If you want to subclass `UITabBarController` then you will have to hide the default tabbar and add your custom to avoid this error.