# Additionally added constraint variation in XCode only works for one device size, how to generalise it for all device sizes?

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, size-classes

I'm using Xcode 13.
I added a variation for a constraint so that when the device's orientation is changed to landscape (Regular-width and Compact-height).

Inside the Xcode I'm using iPhone 11 as demo device.
[image]

And when I actually run it on iPhone 11 simulator, it works fine.

But when I tried running it on other simulators with different screen sizes, like iPhone 12 and 13 Pro, it doesn't work.
[image]

Does that mean inside Xcode I'll have to provide different constraints for all different screen sizes individually ? Or is there a way to do it once and for all ?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317061/how-do-i-use-safe-area-layout-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you have created the constraint with safeArea layout guide an not to superview

[image]